# Remove part of string before last "/"

Tags: regex, r

I want to remove everything before /query .. for e.g

I have no idea about regular expressions so doing this is difficult for me

Note :  the reference should be `/query` as the link mentioned below may have some different patterns like - `www.abcd.wsd/asd/asdcd/asrr/query=xyz`

`www.html.com/query=abcd`

should result into

```
 query = abcd
```

Comment: Use `sub("^.*/(query.*)$", "\\1", s)`. Or if the `query` is limited within `/`: `sub("^.*/(query[^/]*).*$", "\\1", s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic regex solution to extract the `query` appearing after the last `/` and that is followed with characters other than `/` is

```
s <- c("www.abcd.wsd/asd/asdcd/asrr/query=xyz","www.html.com/query=abcd","www.cmpnt.com/query=fgh/noquery=dd")
sub("^.*/(query[^/]*).*$", "\\1", s)
## => "query=xyz"  "query=abcd" "query=fgh"
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/AvPEtK)

The regex is

```
^.*/(query[^/]*).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT2iA6/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - match any 0+ characters as many as possible up to the last
- `/` - a literal forward slash char
- `(query[^/]*)` - capture group 1 matching a `query` substring followed with 0+ characters other than `/` (see `[^/]*` negated character class with a `*` quantifier)
- `.*` - zero or more any characters up to
- `$` - the end of string.

Answer (score 2):

We can *abuse* basename function which was intended to get filename, dropping all folders:

```
basename("www.abcd.wsd/asd/asdcd/asrr/query=xyz")
# [1] "query=xyz"

basename("www.html.com/query=abcd")
# [1] "query=abcd"
```

Note that this will fail when `query` is not at the end:

```
basename("www.html.com/query=abcd/xyz")
# [1] "xyz"
```

Comment: @pankaj sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't get it actually , i am sorry but can you please make me understand that . On what basis this function is returning the last characters ? Is that Slash(/) ?

Comment: @pankaj yes, it returns everything after the last slash `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
sub('.*/query', '/query', 'www.html.com/query=abcd')
```

i.e., replace "all characters up to and including [the last instance of] /query" with "/query".

Answer (score 0):

```
string<-c('www.abcd.wsd/asd/asdcd/asrr/query=xyz','www.html.com/query=abcd')
gsub('.*\\/([^/]+)$','\\1',string)
#[1] "query=xyz"  "query=abcd"
```