# Substring character string based on a certain character in string

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

I have a vector with several elements as character strings split by `/`:

```
aa <- c("Session/1/Focal_011/Dave_1", "Session/2/Focal_223/Dave_2", 
        "Session/3/Focal_23/Quentin_3", "Session/4/Focal_4/Gerald_4",
        "Session/5/Focal_521/Pedro_5")
```

All I want to keep from each element is `Name_n` where `n = element number`.

Can I use `substr` **depending on the `/` character in the string**

Using `substr(aa, 21, nchar(aa))` I get

```
[1] "Dave_1"   "Dave_2"   "uentin_3" "rald_4"   "Pedro_5"
```

This is because the character strings are of different `length`.

How can I standardise it so I just keep from the last `/`?

Using `regex`? If so, how?

Comment: also `basename(aa)`

Comment: I don't agree that it's a duplicate question. I don't see how I can answer my question with the answers given in what you think is the original. But that may be due to my n00bness

Comment: replace the space by "/", which is your separator for "words". It is actually what jilber's answer does, except it takes the 4th word instead of last one (`tail(.., 1)`)

Comment: Thank you Cath, that's really helpful. `basename` is also very good!

Comment: It is an exact dupe IMO since the strings the OP is describing are file paths in which case the name of the file will always be the last 'word'

Comment: @Sotos: What I thought of is that the strings are not necessarily file paths.   Also, `basename` does not work the same in Windows and Linux. I agree there might be an exact duplicate somewhere, but I would not name any "a/b" string a path. But it is just my opinion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't call them paths because of the `/` but because the OP asked the same question before where they stated (if I m not mistaken) that those were file paths...

Comment: @Cath: You mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38634957/4137985)? How can it be the exact dupe? It only grabs a substring in the middle. Ok, it is really very similar.

Comment: @Cath, Well, just double-checked: that answer is certainly different. They look similar, but this one - `"^.*/(.*)$"` get all after the last `/` till the end, whille that one - `"^.*/(query[^/]*).*$"` - will only get a part in the middle or end of string that is after the last `/` but that is followed with `query` and then has 0+ chars other than `/`. Backtracking makes difference when you specify a restrictive context.

Comment: Guys, if I come across a real dupe, I will re-close.

Comment: @Cath: The other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
> aa <- c("Session/1/Focal_011/Dave_1", "Session/2/Focal_223/Dave_2", "Session/3/Focal_23/Quentin_3", "Session/4/Focal_4/Gerald_4", "Session/5/Focal_521/Pedro_5")
> sub("^.*/(.*)$", "\\1", aa)
[1] "Dave_1"    "Dave_2"    "Quentin_3" "Gerald_4"  "Pedro_5"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/JQaA7U).

The `^.*/(.*)$` will match any 0+ chars up to the last `/` and the slash, and then  will capture the rest into Group 1 that will be restored with the `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern.

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you Wiktor!

Comment: @Bonono Yes, but the original thread is still better, you may just use `sub("^.*/", "", aa)`, or `basename`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative using `strsplit`

```
> sapply(strsplit(aa, "/"), "[", 4)
[1] "Dave_1"    "Dave_2"    "Quentin_3" "Gerald_4"  "Pedro_5"
```

Comment: `tail, 1` is much safer than `[, 4` but I guess it's already in the dupe I provided